# Run https on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a docker container app successfully on my virtual Ubuntu 16.04 server in this way:

docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 443:80 app/name

App is running on host port 443, but has anyone an idea how to enable https for this app? I have a valid certificate, but I have no idea how to install and configure this so this docker app is available at https://www.myserver.com and not at http://www.myserver.com:443.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Won't you need to enable that in your app?

Comment: Please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Easiest thing would be to hide your app behind `Nginx` and serve https there. Please be more specific with your question so we can answer it.

Comment: This app is not developed by myself (https://openmaptiles.com/server/). So if I have to enable it in the app, i guess this is not possible? @trust512: do you have an example of how to hide the app behind nginx?

Comment: You can setup nginx to encrypt connections up to the nginx end, and then nginx will proxy these connections unencrypted based on the upstream you'll specify - it's good if the app and nginx are in the same local network so that no one can sniff it easily. Here is a clear [example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/) if this is what you need, then I'll write a answer pointing out steps on how to configure it with docker.